# when selecting from multiple SQL Server 2008 tables is a join inferred?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I found a sproc in a db that I think infers a table join?

Is that accurate to deduce that from the sample below?

```
SELECT a.Column1, b.Column2
  FROM [dbo].[Table1] As a,
  [dbo].[Table2] AS b
```

Comment: All three answers so far are correct, though it is funny they use three different names: natural, Cartesian, cross. This syntax is generally considered bad practice we should be explicit in out joins. And wth a nod toward english.stackexchange.com I thi would say the syntax imploes the join and you infer it. http://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/imply-infer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does infers a join, but that join is a `CROSS JOIN`, which is rarely what you want. It won't simply map each row of `a` to its equivalent in `b`. Instead, it will map each row of `a` to every row of `b`. That is a join, but it's not what we often think of when we talk about joins.

I wanted to show a quick example, but unfortunately SQL Fiddle is down. Sorry!

More on cross joins and cartesian products in SQL Server [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You inferred correctly, this is a Cartesian join.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called a "Natural Join".  You can constrain it with the `WHERE` clause.